# Why is there no DELEGATION embedded in ALFA (from Axiomatics)?

Tags: authorization, access-control, delegation, xacml, alfa

I know there is no such thing as a delegation key-word in ALFA. But I really would like to know why...
Was it because it was too hard to implement or was there an other reason?

Answer (score 1):

It would be relatively simple to implement delegation in ALFA since, after all, all you would need is root policies on the one hand and trusted policies on the other. Trusted policies would have another element called a `PolicyIssuer`. So all we would need in ALFA is the ability to set the issuer.

That said, it's not enough. At runtime, the engine (PDP) would have to determine the chain of trust between root policies and trusted policies. That happens through the `PolicyIssuer`. Different implementations will have different ways of doing it. We did it at Axiomatics using signed policies. That involved having keys to sign with. The reason we didn't provide for delegation in ALFA is that no one really uses it. Administrative delegation is a great idea for sure (our CTO at Axiomatics wrote the profile) but seldom used.